# "Undefined" error using LyX

Tags: errors, lyx

I always get these errors when I try to show a file;

```
LaTeX Error: \eqdeclaration undefined.
LaTeX Error: \pagedeclaration undefined.
LaTeX Error: \nomname undefined.
```

I can't find a fix for that. I didn't find anything about it in the tutorial or in the manuals.

Some one had the same errors years ago. Found it in the [LyX mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=lyx-users&m=132066080601447&w=2). But I can't find an answer. Can somebody help me?

I am using Manjaro Linux!

Comment: Please post a minimal example. Does this happen with any document? If so, make a very simple document and paste it in here (a .lyx file is just plain text). For more information see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 3):

You must define somewhere these control sequences. This can be done in the body of the document in a ERT box, and/or in the LaTeX preamble, directly ( writing yourself in plain TeX `\def\eqdeclaration#1{#1 ...}` or LaTeX code as  as `\newcommand{\eqdeclaration}[1]{#1...}`,  etc.) or including a `.tex` file with these macros  (`\input{mymacros}`) or  a package (`.sty` file) or selecting a document class (`.cls` file) that have these definitions  or load these definitions of another file.

Among all these possibilities, without see a MWE,  I'll guess watching my crystal ball: You need `\usepackage{nomencl}` in the LaTeX Preamble (menu <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> ) but this must be done automatically when you  <kbd>Insert</kbd> any  <kbd>Nomenclature Entry...</kbd>, so at the end, we simply need more information to know the source of these errors. First, make a plain tex file **without Lyx**  named `test.tex` with **any plain text editor**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\begin{document}
\nomname
\eqdeclaration 
\pagedeclaration
\end{document}
```

Then compile the next MWE  in the system prompt with `pdflatex test.tex`. It should produce a `test.pdf` file with a non non-sense text:

> Nomemclature, see equation (, page )")

... but without errors. Otherwise the problem is not related with LyX, but with the LaTeX installation.

Comment: @Max My  MWE cannot just copied & pasted in LyX. I added some clarification. I strongly suggest you first understand  the very basic structure of LaTeX documents (explained in thousands of places) ad how are compiled *without LyX*, then you can understand how LyX make most of this work for you, and what you can do in case of LaTeX errors.